# How can I filter out only those values that have appeared more than once in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have the following data to start with:

```
Sr. No  Conf. By    Prod
1           A         X
2           B         Y
3           A         Z
4           B         X
5           A         X
6           B         Y
7           A         Y
8           B         M
9           A         N
10          B         O
```

I am interested in column `Prod`. I want only those values which have been repeated more than once in column `Prod`.

This is the output I expect after the data has been filtered:

```
 Sr. No Conf. By    Prod
   1        A        X
   2        B        Y
   4        B        X
   5        A        X
   6        B        Y
   7        A        Y
```

Here is what I have done for now. Simply highlighting the duplicate values isn't of much use to me. So I created a pivot table as follows:

[image: Pivot table with "Prod" as row labels & a count of "Prod"]

This gives me a count of how many times each element in `Prod` has been repeated. If I double click on each of the numbers in the `Count of Prod` column it gives me the details of those entries from the original table.

However, I want this for all the items where the count is more than 1.

Any other ideas on how I can get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **D2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,C2)
```

and copy down.  Then apply a filter on column **D** to hide the **1**'s:

[image]

If you want to  hide items appearing twice, hide any **2**'s as well.

Comment: This is almost exactly the answer I was looking for. However, if I have a really long column, it is hard to visualize the repeated items in `Prod` together. So I just sorted the `Prod` column alphabetically and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You're very nearly there.

Right-click one of the `Prod` labels in your PivotTable (eg cell A5 in your example) and select `Filter`, then `Value Filters`. Set `Count of Prod` to be greater than 1.

That's it!

Comment: I'd done that. However, I cannot see the other details of the filtered set unless I double click on the count numbers. And I have to do this for every case where the count is greater than 1 to see the details. Is there a way I can get all the details of my original data after I apply the filters?

Comment: Ah I see. I thought you wanted to do this in the PivotTable. In that case Gary's Student's answer is the one you want!

Comment: Yes, that's really close. However, if my column length is really long it gets difficult to see the repeated items grouped together.